# MongoDB Shell Startup Warnings on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux, mongodb, startup, linux-mint, mongo-shell

The warning messages are below. I'm using Linux Mint 18. When I start the database with "sudo service mongodb start" no warning signs, but when I run the "mongo" shell that's when I encounter this warning messages. Did I miss a step in the installation process? Any advice would be helpful, thank you.

```
--Warnings--
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-08-21T13:23:20.551-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-08-21T13:23:20.551-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-08-21T13:23:20.551-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-08-21T13:23:20.899-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: Related https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160538/mongodb-unable-to-change-mongodb-storage-engine-to-wiredtiger

Comment: These warnings are intended to alert MongoDB administrators to configuration settings that may have potentially detrimental impact (particularly for production deployments). See: [Startup warnings after upgrading from MongoDB 2.6 to 3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894949/startup-warnings-after-upgrading-from-mongodb-2-6-to-3-4).